# PHP - displaying utf-8

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following UTF-8 data in my database:

*ããƒ€ãƒ³ãƒ’ãƒ«*

In japanese:

*ダンヒル*

The field and the database are set to utf_8_general_ci.
I can't figure out how to display the proper japanese characters in my html. Here's what I did so far with no success:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

Also, in my html header, I set the charset to utf-8:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Database connection is mysqli, `set_charset` is set to utf-8.

Note that using this [tool](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder), I managed to encode my string to the proper japense characters.

Any help, would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd guess your DB connection isn't set to UTF8. You have `ããƒ€ãƒ³ãƒ’ãƒ«` in the DB or `ダンヒル`?

Comment: I have `ããƒ€ãƒ³ãƒ’ãƒ«`.

Comment: Okay so when you inserted it wasn't set as UTF8 you're going to need to re-insert the data as well. Can you please add the DB connection you are using to the question?

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. I inherited a 17 years old database today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the beginning of your code.

**OR,**

**MySql:**

Try to set charachter encoding after mysql_connect function like this:

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'"); 
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 

mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

**Mysqli:**

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

 /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
  }

  /* change character set to utf8 */
  if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
      printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  } else {
      printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
  }

  $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: The OP has this

Comment: I have updated some code..try this..

Comment: Thank you, but yes, I already have `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` in my database connection.